# Java Buffered Reader Reads In Part of the URL to String then Hangs (Is there a size limit?)

Tags: java, url, networking, network-programming

I am trying to read a URL into a String and it starts reading in the URL and then just stops at the same line every time and hangs.  This happens with any URL and it happens when I run the program from the command line on Windows 7.  When I run the same program in Eclipse it never hangs and reads in the entire website.

It always gets to "got to line 2" and inside of the while loop but never to "line 3".

Here is the code I am using below.  Is there some type of a size limit or something when doing it right through Windows on the command line?

```
URL link = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
System.out.println("got to this line 1");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

System.out.println("got to this line 2");
        //InputStream in = link.openStream();
        String inputLine = "";
        int count = 0;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            site = site + "\n" + inputLine;
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        System.out.println("exited the while loop.");
        in.close();
        System.out.println("got to this line 3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took that code, put it in a main method, added a `site` variable as `String site = "";`, compiled it with IntelliJ, and ran it from a Windows 7 command prompt, and it worked fine:

```
> java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Output of the program:

```
got to this line 1
got to this line 2
<all of the page source>
exited the while loop.
got to this line 3
```

Does it work the same if you comment out the line that prints out each line as its read in?

Comment: The same error happens if I comment out the line.  The only difference is my Java version is:  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: @Ray: I get exactly the same result with `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)`